# What does "presentedViewController" in UIViewController mean?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

In Apple's developer documentation, the property presentedViewController in UIViewController is described as "The view controller that is presented by this view controller, or one of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy". It is confusing. What does "its ancestors" mean?

Comment: Self maybe?? I agree, it's confusing.

Answer (score 6):

This question is really old, but it was still the top Google hit for my search, and the existing answer is wrong and makes things even more misleading.

This property always returns a presented view controller (or nil), it will never return an ancestor view controller. What the reference to ancestors means is that if the view controller you call it on isn't presenting any view controller itself then it will walk up the hierarchy to see if any parent view controllers are presenting anything.

For a concrete example - let's say you have ContentViewController which is a contained within a UINavigationController. The NavigtionController is currently presenting another view controller (perhaps a UIAlertViewController for example).

In this case the presentedViewController property of both the ContentViewController and the NavigationController will return the UIAlertController that is being presented by the NavigationController. When this is dismissed it will return nil for both of them.

So to add a bit more clarity to the line in the Apple Docs:
"The view controller that is presented by this view controller, or [the view controller presented by] one of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy."

Answer (score -1):

There are two view controllers, viewA and viewB. viewA presents viewB. Now this is what the documentation is referring to:

### Example 1 ( calling viewA.presentedViewController )

This will return viewB, because viewA **presented** viewB

### Example 2 ( calling viewB.presentedViewController )

This will return viewA because viewA is an **ancestor** of viewB. In other words, imagine these two views in a line. viewB is second in line while viewA is first. So a view's **ancestor** is the view *behind* itself.

Only reason why this function call on viewB returns viewA is because viewB did not present any other view controller. Or in other words, viewB is on the **top of the hierarchy**. There is no view *in front* of viewB.

Comment: When would this be useful? I'm dealing with some legacy code right now that called this and I can't determine why they thought it would be useful.

Comment: Perhaps the call came from a controller that had a reference to the view controller and the controller needed to know what view did it present? I never found any use of presented view controller but I have used parent view controller, that for sure

Comment: This answer isn't correct. The property always returns a presented view controller (or nil), it's just one that is either presented by the current view controller, or presented by one of the ancestors of the current view controller. I've added full details in another answer.